# How do I get my own hotspot ip address in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, hotspot

I have a problem getting an IP address on my own hotspot. I found several plugins and found nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You must check IP address on your device.

If you using phone for hotspot, follow this:

1. Open **setting**.
2. Open **about phone**.
3. Open **status**.
4. In the status list, there is an **IP address** section.